# Is it "improvement of environment" or "the improvement of environment"?

Tags: grammar

> Three benefits of globalization are the improvement of environment,
> the integration of knowledge, and the development of new innovations.
>
> Three benefits of globalization are improvement of environment,
> integration of knowledge, and development of new innovations.

Which one of the above sentences is correct?

I'm not sure if I should add "the" before "improvement", "integration", and "development"

Comment: What is the source of this quote, please? Did you write it,? If not, who did and where did you read it? If it is from someone else's work, please provide a link if possible, and title and author in any case. Also, what makes you think that "the" should be used, or not used, in these phrases?

Comment: @DavidSiegel I wrote this myself. I didn't know if "the" should be used because I've seen examples with "the" and without "the". Here are some examples: https://glosbe.com/en/en/improvement%20of%20environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write this as:

> Three benefits of globalization are the improvement of the environment, the integration of knowledge, and the development of new innovations.

I would use "the" before each list item, because it is a specific benefit being cited by the speaker. I would use "the" before "environment" because "the environment" is a fixed phrase, used to refer to the environment in general, not any specific environment, just as "the ocean" is used to refer to all oceans in general, as well as to the specific water that one is standing in or sailing over. "I went for a swim in the ocean."